# how do i add css to a drupal 7 view

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a view in the back-end named 'photo gallery'.
I have CSS in `style.css` where class name is

```
.gallery{...};
```

I want my photo gallery to have the .gallery CSS.

In the views block I have tried giving the Css as

```
settings-> add field html-> add css class-> .gallery
```

but its not taking the css. is there any other way? what am i doing wrong here?

can anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: I think you just need to  use gallery not .gallery in your add css class

Comment: `settings-> add feild html-> add css class-> gallery` not `.gallery`

Comment: Are you looking to give the entire view a class? Or individual items/rows or fields a class? In my own experience, if you're looking to make the views classes match up perfectly with whatever pre-existing css you have, it may be tricky. If you're able to modify the CSS though, in addition to what others have said, there's a CSS field in the "Advanced" tab of the view that you can get around the entire thing also.

Comment: I want to add css to the images and also to the view. each image should take up the css.

Answer (score 0):

drupal should add wrappers to your view by default, the correct CSS class to use should be:

```
.view-photo-gallery{}
```

or when it's in a block:

```
#block-views-photo-gallery-view-block{}
```

Also classes for first, last, even and odd rown will be added.

If these don't work, use inspector to determine the correct classes